# How do I make fancybox use its larger icons

Tags: jquery, fancybox

How can I make fancybox 2 use its larger icons versions? this ones (fancybox_loading@2x.gif, fancybox_sprite@2x.png)

This sucks I have to write something so this page will allow me to post my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those 2x icons were created for devices with *retina display* support. If you analyze the fancybox CSS file, at the end you will find these lines :

```
/*Retina graphics!*/
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
       only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
       only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5){

    #fancybox-loading, .fancybox-close, .fancybox-prev span, .fancybox-next span {
        background-image: url(fancybox_sprite@2x.png);
        background-size: 44px 152px; /*The size of the normal image, half the size of the hi-res image*/
    }

    #fancybox-loading div {
        background-image: url(fancybox_loading@2x.gif);
        background-size: 24px 24px; /*The size of the normal image, half the size of the hi-res image*/
    }
}
```

If you wan to use them in a none-retina-display support device or browser, I guess you may need to hack the CSS file and change the regular icon's dimensions and sprites to match those in the *media queries*